# Why does syncing with the Ropsten testnet appear to pause?

Tags: synchronization, testnets, ropsten

I am running a node with geth via the command `geth --testnet --fast --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303"`

It is on block 924332 and I am trying to sync the full blockchain, but am getting a lot of warnings that say

> Synchronisation failed, retrying

and

> Ancestor below allowance

There are currently 986074 blocks in the blockchain (https://ropsten.etherscan.io/), and all I am getting in the console is those warnings and it no longer shows how many blocks are "pending", so I'm assuming that it thinks no blocks are left. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?